# Set of increasing functions closed in the product topology of $\mathbb{R}^I$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $I$ be the unit interval and consider $\Bbb R^I$ with the product topology. Is the set $\{f \in \Bbb R^I \mid f \text{ increasing } \}$ a closed set in $\Bbb R^I$?

Is there a pictorial way to see this? The complement is the set $\{f \in \Bbb R^I \mid \exists\ x<y \text{ s.t } f(x) > f(y)\}$ so if $f \in A^c$ and $A^c$ is to be open there would need to exist $\bigcap_{x \in F} \pi^{-1}_x(U_x)$ where $F$ is a finite subset of $I$ and $\pi_x$ is the projection.

The way I've been picturing the product space with the product topology is the following

[image]

here the vertical lines are copies of $\Bbb R$ and the small vertical lines denote the sets $V_x$ and so the set $\bigcap_{x \in F}\pi_x^{-1}(V_x)$ is the set of all functions passing through these small vertical lines.

So I am looking to see if there is an open set of this form whenever there is points $x < y$ for which $f(x) > f(y)$?

Comment: I tried to answer completely to the question, It seems to me (and should be the most intuitive expectation) that the set of non-decreasing function is exactly the closure of the set of the increasing functions. Please let me know if you are agree with me 

Comment: Thank you! I will read your proof and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

The convergence in $\mathbb R^I$ is the pointwise convergence. Knowing this, consider $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $I=[0,1]$ for $n\ge 1$. Then $f_n$ is increasing for every $n\ge 1$ but $f=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ is the function $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,1)$ and $f(1)=1$. Therefore, $f$ is not increasing.

We found a sequence of elements of $A=\left\{ f\in \mathbb R^I \middle| f \text{ increasing}\right\}$ whose limit is not in $A$, so $A$ is not closed.

Comment: Hmm what about *non-decreasing*?

Comment: This is unfortunately not true. The set $A$ is closed.

Comment: @SleepWalker: can you point to a specific problem in my reasoning?

Comment: I don't find a flaw in it, but I think that you cannot consider sequences since $\Bbb R^I$ is not metrizable. Instead of sequences we should use nets. I presume that will lead to a flaw.

Answer (score 1):

About *non-decreasing* question, consider the projections $p_x\colon \mathbb{R}^I\to \mathbb{R}$ sending $p_{x}(f):=f(x)$.

Of course $p_x$ is continuos for every $x\in I$, by definition of product topology. Thus is continuos also the product functions $p_x\times p_y\colon \mathbb{R}^I\to \mathbb{R}^2$ sending $f$ to $(f(x),f(y))$. Consider the following closed set $\Delta^\geq:= \{ (x,y): x\geq y\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and open set $\Delta^>:=\{\{ (x,y): x> y\}$.

Then the set of functions $S_{N-D}$ that are *non-decreasing* is

$$S_{N-D}=\cap_{x_0\in I}\cap_{x_1\geq x_0}\left(p_{x_1}\times p_{x_0}\right)^{-1}(\Delta^\geq)$$

that is closed.

I think that here you can just see with your eyes which is the problem for the *increasing functions*. In fact the set $S_I$ of the  *increasing functions* is

$$S_{I}=\cap_{x_0\in I}\cap_{x_1\geq x_0}\left(p_{x_1}\times p_{x_0}\right)^{-1}(\Delta^>)$$

However $\Delta^>$ is not closed, so it makes sense that the set is not necessarily closed. In fact Taladris answer shows you a counter-example.

I think we can say something more! How we would have (it’s just an intuition), we can expect that product topology is so nice that the closure of the set of *increasing functions* is exactly the closed set of *non-decreasing functions*.

> $$cl(S_I)=S_{N-D}.$$
> *proof*. Of course
> $$S_{I}=\cap_{x_0\in I}\cap_{x_1\geq x_0}\left(p_{x_1}\times p_{x_0}\right)^{-1}(\Delta^>)\subseteq \cap_{x_0\in I}\cap_{x_1\geq x_0}\left(p_{x_1}\times p_{x_0}\right)^{-1}(\Delta^\geq)=S_{N-D}$$ but the right set is closed, so by closure property we have
> $$cl(S_I)\subseteq S_{N-D}.$$ Let $f\in S_{N-D}$. An open neighborhood of $f$ in the product topology is the Union of a *finite intersection* of neighbourhoods $p_x^{-1}((-\epsilon +f(x), f(x)+\epsilon))$. Thus, for proving that $f$ is in the boundary of $S_I$ is sufficient to prove that any open neighborhood $U:=\cap_{i=1}^k p_{x_i}^{-1}((-\epsilon_i +f(x), f(x)+\epsilon_i))$ intersects always $S_I$. Let $\epsilon:= min(\epsilon_i)$ and define $F\in \mathbb{R}^I$ such that $F(x):=f(x)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}x$. By construction $F$ belongs to the neighborhood $U$ of $f$ and is also an increasing function, that means $F\in S_I\cap U$. So $f\in cl(S_I)$ and we are done.

Comment: Let $f \in A^c$, then $\exists x,y$ s.t $x < y$ and $f(x) > f(y)$. Suppose that $f(x) > a > f(y)$. Let $U = \{f \in \Bbb R^I \mid f(x) > a \text{ and } f(y) < a \} = \{f \in \Bbb R^I \mid f(x) > a \} \cap \{f \in \Bbb R^I \mid f(y) < a \} = \pi_x^{-1}(a, \infty) \cap \pi_y^{-1}(-\infty, a)$. This is a open set containing $f$ implying that $A$ is closed.

Comment: @SleepWalker maybe you are saying that the set A^c is open? Give me time to understand what is written

Comment: Exactly. If $A^c$ is open, then $A$ is closed. Sure no problem. Let me know if you find something wrong in the reasoning.

Comment: @SleepWalker so you wanna prove that A is closed? Non the set of non-decreasing functions?

Comment: Yes sorry. I was denoting $\{f \in \Bbb R^I \mid f \text{ increasing } \}$ as $A$ as I didn't want to write it all the time.